# give inputs to android library app from main app

Tags: android

I have created android library project as well as main project.I connected my library project to main project.Its working fine.But i want to give some inputs to library project from main project.Is it possible in android?

Comment: pass value as in? Call some asynctask, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
    {
        int initailDelay=extras.getInt("initialDelay");
    }
```

Try this code for retrieving value

Answer (score 0):

Library is part of your application, you can use it like normal code.

Comment: i set values like Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  initialDelay = 1;
  intent.putExtra("initialDelay", initialDelay);i get this value from getIntent().getStringExtra("initialDelay").toString();but i am getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Post more logs and code, which exact line throws exception?